# How to start a python application after installation with setup.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py

I am installing a package using `python2 setup.py install`.
This package is a tkinter application which contains traditional

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried running `python2 -m my_app` or `python2 -m my_app.__main__` and `python2 -c "import my_app"` but I either get an error or nothing happens.

I can run it `./my_app.py` from console.

How can I run my python application after installation with `setup.py`?

Comment: `./my_app.py`. That or double click on it (assuming the python interpreter is set to open .py files). I'm confused what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import module with `main` function and call it

```
python -c "from some_module import main; main()"
```

but mostly modules/apps, simply expose bin/scripts, look in `bin` dir of your virtualenv or `setup.py`.

More info about how to expose (scripts, entry_points):

- http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html
- https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

Comment: I see, I am getting `ImportError: cannot import name main` though but `main()` function exists.